Intents are mapping to other form
I’ve two forms form1 and form2, which have similar kind of entites, eg. form1 has mobile_number and form2 has emergency_mobile_number.
Now when I’m at form1 and entering mobile_number, rasa misclassifies the entered value into emergency_mobile_number because the training examples for both are same.
I’m anyone to resolve it, can anyone help regarding this?
